# Предложение с двумя двоеточиями

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксический-разбор

> Рот наполнился вязкой, как тина, слюной: у нее был странный вкус, но теперь Эрик узнал его: это был вкус страха — едкого, глубинного, зловещего
>
> [Империя волков](https://books.google.ee/books?id=v0zWrIaUQOMC&pg=PT219&lpg=PT219&dq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81&source=bl&ots=ICFs8pyzlv&sig=-RHOf-qNMyecUOHxykM0LLTy2Bo&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiw-jl1oHTAhXHkSwKHXNfBZEQ6AEIFzAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81&f=false)

Вроде бы все правильно, но предложение воспринимается как-то *неудобно*, разрозненно.

Хочу спросить у Форума:

- к какому типу предложений его "отнести"?
- как бы Вы его оформили, не меняя порядка слов?

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: "...как бы Вы его оформили, не меняя порядка слов?"_ === Я бы после слова "слюной" поставил бы точку.

Comment: Можно и точку с запятой.

Answer (score 1):

**В качестве варианта:** Рот наполнился вязкой, как тина, слюной. У нее был странный вкус, но теперь Эрик узнал его: это был вкус страха — едкого, глубинного, зловещего.

Мне кажется, что такая разбивка оптимальна, так как первое предложение вполне самодостаточно по содержанию и в качестве самостоятельной единицы лучше выделяется в тексте.

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста, а как мы с Вами это предложение разберем ( это тоже часть вопроса ) ? Конечно, я давно уже не школьница, но мозги хотелось бы поднапрячь. С Вашей помощью,  если возможно... Я-то запуталась.

Comment: Разбираем второе предложение. Состоит из трех предикативных основ, между 1 и 2,3 связь сочинительная (союз НО), между 2 и 3 связь бессоюзная, предложение 3 раскрывает содержание предложения 2 (ставится двоеточие), в конце предложения 3 находится обособленный  с помощью тире ряд однородных определений.

Comment: Еще раз извините, но я имела в виду оригинальное предложение.  С уважением...

Comment: А  в оригинальном предложении добавляется первое предложение, ставится двоеточие, и все последующие раскрывают его тему (тему слюны). Второе двоеточие раскрывает тему страха.  Два двоеточия в одном предложении не очень приветствуются, но допускаются.

Answer (score 0):

Первое двоеточие я бы заменил на запятую.